# How to make dynamically parameters django models fields

Tags: python, django, django-models

This code is a abstract class for many

```
Class Base (models.Model):
    Created_by = models.ForeignKey(User)
    Modified_by = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True)
```

I want related_name like this `related_name = self.default_related_name + '_name_field'`
As the following

```
Class Base(models.Model):
    Created_by = models.ForeignKey(User,
        related_name = self.default_related_name + '_created_by')
    Modified_by = models.ForeignKey(User,
        null = True,
        related_name = self.default_related_name + '_modified_by')
```

But i know that, I cant have access to instance in the attributes of the class.
So what method do I can to overload to create a field with a method (or property)?
(I tried to create the field in the `__init__` method, but it doesnt not work).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can use the subclass name instead of default_related_name then it's trivial:

```
related_name="%(class)s_created"
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/models/#be-careful-with-related-name

Also, as the base class is a abstract model, you will need

```
class Meta:
    abstract = True
```

Comment: Thanks you, but why it's trivial ?

Answer (score 0):

Pre save signal is what you are looking for.

for reference : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/signals/#pre-save

right before save it to the database, you can apply all the changes you want. :)

here is an example where I capitalize the first letter of every word and create a slug.

```
def pre_save_city(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
instance.name = instance.name.title()
if not instance.slug:
    instance.slug = slugify(instance.name)
```

this is how you run the function :

```
pre_save.connect(pre_save_city,sender=City)
```

Comment: No, my explain of my problem is may bad, i wanted to dynamically create the value of the parameters 'related_name' for avoid the errors (fields.E304)